# Add bands to data based on values from another table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and have just started learnign it. I'm currently stuck on a step in some data manipulation i'm doin, info is below:

I have a table of distences between zones in the below structure:

Table 1: DISTANCES

```
From_Zone        To_Zone        Distance
  1                 1              1.5
  1                 2              3
  1                 3              4
  1                 4              5
  2                 1              1
  .                 .              . 
  .                 .              .
```

and so on...

and i have another table of distance bands as the below structure:

Table 2: BANDS

```
Min_Distance         Max_Distance         Band
    0                    1                 1
    1                    2                 2
    2                    4                 3
    .                    .                 .
```

and so on...

I want to add a new 'Band' column to Table 1 based on the bands on the distance. i.e. if distance from zone 1 to zone 3 is 2.5, then band is 3 and result table should look like:

```
From_Zone        To_Zone        Distance     Band
  1                 1            1.5         2
  1                 2            3           3
  .                 .            .           .
```

and so on...

I've been trying the cut function but i cannot seem to make it work reading bins from Min_Distance and Max_Distance in Table 2.

```
pd.cut(Distance.Distance, bins=Bands.Bins, labels=False)
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.cut` expects an array like defining the bin edges. You can build that with:

```
Distance['Band'] = pd.cut(Distance.Distance, [Bands.Min_Distance.min()]
                          + Bands.Max_Distance.tolist(), labels=Bands.Band)
```

Comment: This returns a str, is there a way to make it return an integer? 
Thanks.

Comment: Is `astype(int)` enough?